# Find is date between array of start and end dates

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I have a array of objects containing dates, if a user added another start and end date it cannot overlap with any existing dates in the array.

Using `Moment` I have this loop but no alert is fired when I input a date that overlaps

Using the input dates, `startDate: "2013-09-02T00:00:00", endDate: "2015-05-05T00:00:0`, the loop over the last array item should fire the alert, as the dates overlap.

```
  let resultData = data.row;
    let array = this.props.sectionData;

    let inputStartDate = Moment(resultData.startDate, "DD/MM/YYYY");
    let inputEndDate   = Moment(resultData.endDate, "DD/MM/YYYY");

    array.forEach( function (i) {

        if(i.startDate && i.endDate) {

            let startDate = Moment(i.startDate, "DD/MM/YYYY");
            let endDate = Moment(i.endDate, "DD/MM/YYYY");

            if (inputStartDate.isBetween(startDate, endDate) || inputEndDate.isBetween(startDate, endDate)) {
                alert('date range cannot overlap');
            }
        }

    });
```

My data:

```
[
{"id": 3,
"startDate": 2013-09-01T00:00:00,
"endDate": 2013-09-01T00:00:00,
"description": null,
"userId": 900,
"userName": "",
"documents": [],
},
{
"id": 5,
"startDate": 2013-09-01T00:00:00,
"endDate": 2013-09-01T00:00:00,
"description": null,
"userId": 1,
"userName": "",
"documents": [],
"contributors": []
},
{
"id": 6,
"startDate": "2013-09-01T00:00:00",
"endDate": "2014-08-31T00:00:00",
"description": "content",
"userId": 1,
"userName": ""
},
```

Comment: have you checked it is definitely entering the loop, at least?

Comment: also, startdate and enddate are in YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss format, but you're asking Moment to parse them as DD/MM/YYYY - that probably won't work

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Yes, for the valid dates is checking them

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your comment - what is checking what for valid dates? If you use moment(i.startDate, "DD/MM/YYYY") on a date that is not in DD/MM/YYYY format, it will fail to parse it and you will not get a valid moment object. That in turn will cause your date comparison to fail, possibly with javascript errors in the console.

Comment: ...continued: From the sample data you have posted, startDate and endDate are not in DD/MM/YYYY format, so moment will not recognise them using the code you have written. Does simply calling moment(i.startDate) work? If not, you'll need to specify the correct format. See http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let moment parse the object.  See https://plnkr.co/edit/OqKNDsSWvcMc3PXOcu9F?p=preview for a working example.

Explanation:

```
let inputStartDate = moment("2013-09-02T00:00:00");
let inputEndDate   = moment("2015-05-05T00:00:00");
```

As ADyson explained your were passing in the incorrect formats.  Also you are missing quotes in your test data around your dates for ids 3 and 5.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, its the dates in my loop that are showing as invalid, how would i format them from the json?

Comment: The same way as you do for the one with id of 6 presumably :)  Can you show your code that creates the array or is that just test data?